# Чем отличается Внедрение через конструктор и Внедрение через метод?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Помогите разобраться в DI (Dependency Injection), а конкретно, чем отличается Внедрение через конструктор и Внедрение через метод? Если можно, то желательно с примерами

Comment: Слишком расплывчатый вопрос. Это примерно как "чем отличается писать ручкой от писать карандашом"

Comment: тем, что в одном случае внедряется в момент создания объекта, при вызове конструктора, а в другом - при вызове метода.

Comment: @Kromster и в чем отличия?)

Comment: @Grundy, хорошо, но зачем тогда делить, можно все сделать через внедрение через конструктор, смысл от внедрения через метод?

Comment: @Nikita, то что бросается в глаза - разное время жизни, в совокупности с разными настройками в DI можно довольно гибко настраивать когда создавать новый объект зависимости, а когда переиспользовать старый

Comment: разница кажется очевидной. При внедорении через конструктор, нужны все зависимости, чтобы создать объект. То есть объект не будет создан, если зависимости еще не созданы. При внедрении через метод, зависимости нужны чисто в динамике - только тогда, когда они конкретно будут использованы, необъодимость внедрения обуславливается не существованием объекта, а каким то сценарием использования.

Comment: @tym32167 разместите как ответ? Он правильнее другого данного )

Comment: @Kromster удалил недоправильный ответ

Comment: @aepot просто обновите его как считаете нужным, можете просто мой коммент туда вставить, если хотите )

Comment: @Kromster я не против если дополнят существующий ответ, там тоже много полезной инфы есть =)

Comment: @Nikita зачем - другой вопрос, и ответ на него обычно "затем". К примеру, не всегда есть доступ к конструктору, особенно при интеграции со старыми фреймворками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница кажется очевидной.

При внедрении через конструктор, предполагается, что для создания объекта зависимости необходимы (наравне с другими аргументами передаваемыми в конструктор). То есть, если зависимости еще не созданы, без них, объект не имеет смысла и не может быть создан.

При внедрении через метод, зависимости опциональны или нужны чисто в динамике - только тогда, когда они конкретно будут использованы. Т.е. необходимость внедрения обуславливается не существованием объекта, а каким-то сценарием использования.

---

Другими словами - различные варианты/решения диктуются различным дизайном и архитектурой системы и задают её предполагаемое использование.